# What is the default policy for AuthorizeFilter?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-authorization

Most of the code I have seen is applied with policy. What is the default policy for AuthorizeFilter? `options.Filters.Add(new AuthorizeFilter())`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The default policy for ASP.NET Core is that user is authenticated. check out here 
https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/blob/16a47948f80fede807fabe3c291d793590e8fd17/src/Security/Authorization/Core/src/AuthorizationOptions.cs#L28

```
public AuthorizationPolicy DefaultPolicy { get; set; } = new AuthorizationPolicyBuilder().RequireAuthenticatedUser().Build();
```

You can override the default policy in startup.cs

```
services.AddAuthorization(options =>
{
    options.DefaultPolicy = new AuthorizationPolicyBuilder()
    .RequireAuthenticatedUser()
    .RequireClaim("AdminClaim")
    .Build();
});
```